# App Script How to utilize Utilities.getUuid(); for concurrent and simultaneous use by users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**UPDATE Note**: Users only have access to this script through the library I shared with them, hence all users will be concurrently running this very code at the same time.

I am trying to find a way to avoid overwriting the last row if two users run the script at the same time, however there is only 1 script being used and users only have library access to the function.

I have updated the code for a thorough review.

```
  while (switchs == "True"){
  Logger.log("Starting While loop \n Do we have the lock =====> " + lock.hasLock())
  var date_name = [date, name]
  Logger.log(date_name)
  ////////Appending row after lastrow+1 creates empty rows in the range between the values
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master Tracker").appendRow(date_name);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  if (target.getRange(1 + lastRow).getDisplayValue() == date && target.getRange(2 + lastRow).getDisplayValue() == name){
      for (var n = 0; n <= tarRange.length+1; n++){
        if(target.getRange("A" + (n+2)).getDisplayValue() !== ""){
          Logger.log(" ----------------------------------------------- Checking Row Values")
          var check_date = target.getRange("A" + (n+2)).getDisplayValue();
          var check_name = target.getRange("B" + (n+2)).getDisplayValue();
          Logger.log("Checking Date First -- " + check_date)
          Logger.log("Checking name First -- " + check_name)
          Logger.log("Tracker name -- > " + name)
          Logger.log("Original Date -- > " + date)
          if (name == check_name && date == check_date){
            switchs = "False"
            insert = "True"
            var rownum = (n+2)  
            Logger.log("Row Number is ====> " + rownum)
            Utilities.sleep(3000);
            if (insert == "True"){
              Logger.log("=================================== |||||||| INSERT IS TRUE |||| =======================")
              for (var n = 0; n <= tarRange.length+1; n++){
                Logger.log(" ----------------------------------------------- Checking Row Values")
                var check_date = target.getRange("A" + rownum).getDisplayValue();
                var check_name = target.getRange("B" + rownum).getDisplayValue();
                Logger.log("Checking Date First -- " + check_date)
                Logger.log("Checking name First -- " + check_name)
                Logger.log("Tracker name -- > " + name)
                Logger.log("Original Date -- > " + date)
                for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
                  var row = data[i];  
                  var cat_name =  row[0];
                  var cat_count = row[1];
                  Logger.log(" ----------- Tracker Queue Name > " + cat_name)      
                  for (var x = 2; x < headers.length; x++){
                      var header = headers[x];
                      if (cat_name == header){
                        if(check_name !== "" && check_date !== ""){
                            Logger.log(" ----------------------------------------- Getting Column Names")
                            Logger.log(" ------- Database Queue > " + header)
                            Logger.log(" ----- - Tracker Queue > " + cat_name)
                            Logger.log("==========================================================================LOOOKING FOR ===== ...> " + name + " and currently have... " + check_name)
                            Logger.log("==========================================================================LOOOKING FOR =====  ...> " + date + " and currently have ... " + check_date)
                            if ( name == check_name && date == check_date){  
                                Logger.log("=========|||||========= We have name match ===============|||||||||===============...> " + name + "and ... " + check_name)
                                Logger.log("===========|||||======== We have date match =========|||||||====================...> " + date + "and ... " + check_date)
                                Logger.log("Do we have the lock =====> " + lock.hasLock())  
                                Logger.log(" ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Overwriting Previous Entry")
                                colNum = getColByName(cat_name);  
                                Logger.log(colNum)
                                target.getRange(rownum, colNum).setValue(cat_count)
                                switchs = "False"
                            
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is in the header, I have tried all locks script n doc nothing works since it's the same instance of code being used however if it is ran within the same sheet then the locks work like they would but my case is multiple users from multiple sheets that only have libraries added to their App Scripts which contains my Script, all running at the same time.

**Any help would be great!**

I have read a bit about Utilities.getUuid(); but I'm unsure how to implement it here.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getUuid()

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your feedback, I have read that and I'm yet to figure out how to implement it.?

Comment: They're not guaranteed to be unique in all situations.